# Can I set environment variable in node.js depending on domain?

Tags: node.js, heroku

Can I set environment variables depending on which domain the request is going through?

What I am thinking about is that I've got my node.js application up and running, I assign two domains, the same domain, with different TLD:s like below

```
mydomain.fr
mydomain.de
```

and doing something like this pseudo code

```
switch(app.host) {
  case 'mydomain.fr':
    process.env.LANGUAGE = 'fr';
  break;

  case 'mydomain.de':
    process.env.LANGUAGE = 'de';
  break;

  default:
    process.env.LANGUAGE = 'en';
  break;
}
```

I am thinkg about doing this way because I'd really like to use a node module like `i18n` or similar but using the same code base then just add different language variables in specific json files.

This would make it a lot easier if I would like to launch my website in a new country like Italy (.it) or anything else. If I push an update to the website it's automatically pushed to all languages.

My main question is now first: **Is this possible?**
and second what are the pros and especially cons for this approach? I've already listed some pros and right now the only con I can think of is that one web server needs to be larger/stronger than I would've need if I set the page up on different servers.

Worth mentioning is that the traffic on each language site is rather low (below 10k per month for both languages)

Another mention that could be worth mentioning is that I'm planning to deploy these websites to Heroku if that would matter.

Answer (score 2):

It wouldn't work if two domains run simultaneously.

Global variables like `process` in node.js are just that: global. What would happen if you run two services (apps) is that the first will set the variable `process.env.LANGUAGE` to something and the second will overwrite it.

It wouldn't even work if you do it per-connection. The first customer from France will set `process.env.LANGUAGE` to `fr` then the second customer from Germany will set it to `de` then by the time you respond to the first customer (who is French) you will end up giving him the page in German.

Remember, while node.js is only single threaded we still need to worry about multiple connections because they can be concurrent.

---

The correct place to attach something like this is the variable that you uniquely get for each connection: the request object and response object (usually abbreviated as `req` and `res`). If you want something standard-ish, add a pseudo-header to the request object using a middleware. I'd personally just do `req.lang = 'de'`;